# Predicting the price of the natural gas using LSTM neural network

Tags: keras, neural-network, regression, lstm, prediction

I want to build a model using Keras to predict the price of the natural gas.
The dataset contains the price for the gas daily and monthly since 1997 and it is available [Here](https://datahub.io/core/natural-gas).

The following graph shows the prices during a sequence of days. X is days and Y is the price.

[image]

I have tried LSTM with 4,50,100 cell in hidden layer but the accuracy still not was bad and the model failed to predict future price.
I have added another two hidden layers (full connected) with 100 and 128 cell but it did not work too.

This is the model and the result form training process:

```
num_units = 100
activation_function = 'sigmoid'
optimizer = 'adam'
loss_function = 'mean_squared_error'
batch_size = 5
num_epochs = 10
log_file_name = f"{SEQ_LEN}-SEQ-{1}-PRED-{int(time.time())}"

# Initialize the model (of a Sequential type)
model = Sequential()

# Adding the input layer and the LSTM layer
model.add(LSTM(units = num_units, activation = activation_function,input_shape=(None, 1)))

# Adding the output layer
model.add(Dense(units = 1))

# Compiling the RNN
model.compile(optimizer = optimizer, loss = loss_function, metrics=['accuracy'])

# Using the training set to train the model
history = model.fit(train_x, train_y, batch_size = batch_size, epochs =num_epochs,validation_data=(test_x, test_y))
```

and the output is :

> Train on 4362 samples, validate on 1082 samples
>
> Epoch 1/10
>   4362/4362 [==============================] - 11s 3ms/step - loss: 0.0057 - acc: 2.2925e-04 - val_loss: 0.0016 - val_acc: 0.0018
>
> Epoch 2/10
>   4362/4362 [==============================] - 9s 2ms/step - loss: 6.2463e-04 - acc: 4.5851e-04 - val_loss: 0.0013 - val_acc: 0.0018
>
> Epoch 3/10
>   4362/4362 [==============================] - 9s 2ms/step - loss: 6.1073e-04 - acc: 2.2925e-04 - val_loss: 0.0014 - val_acc: 0.0018
>
> Epoch 4/10
>   4362/4362 [==============================] - 8s 2ms/step - loss: 5.4403e-04 - acc: 4.5851e-04 - val_loss: 0.0014 - val_acc: 0.0018
>
> Epoch 5/10
>   4362/4362 [==============================] - 7s 2ms/step - loss: 5.4765e-04 - acc: 4.5851e-04 - val_loss: 0.0012 - val_acc: 0.0018
>
> Epoch 6/10
>   4362/4362 [==============================] - 8s 2ms/step - loss: 5.1991e-04 - acc: 4.5851e-04 - val_loss: 0.0013 - val_acc: 0.0018
>
> Epoch 7/10
>   4362/4362 [==============================] - 7s 2ms/step - loss: 5.7324e-04 - acc: 2.2925e-04 - val_loss: 0.0011 - val_acc: 0.0018
>
> Epoch 8/10
>   4362/4362 [==============================] - 7s 2ms/step - loss: 4.4248e-04 - acc: 4.5851e-04 - val_loss: 0.0011 - val_acc: 0.0018
>
> Epoch 9/10
>   4362/4362 [==============================] - 7s 2ms/step - loss: 4.3868e-04 - acc: 4.5851e-04 - val_loss: 0.0011 - val_acc: 0.0018
>
> Epoch 10/10
>   4362/4362 [==============================] - 7s 2ms/step - loss: 4.6654e-04 - acc: 4.5851e-04 - val_loss: 0.0011 - val_acc: 0.0018

How to know the number of layers and cells for problem like this? Anyone can suggest a netwrok structure that can solve this problem?

Comment: Could you please add some punctuation to your sentences? I find it really hard to read your question this way.

Comment: What I understand so far is that you're trying to predict the price of gas based only on previous gas prices. What makes you think that previous gas prices have all the information needed to predict future prices? In fact, I would say that the price today is totally unrelated to the price last year. Many, many things affect these prices, you need to include those things in your model.

Comment: yes it is just the start my project is for stock prices but as you know oil gas gold and dollar effect on the stock prices